Why do $F \cdot \mathrm{d}x$ and change in kinetic energy give different value of work done by external force?
Method 1: Using Force and Displacement
Displacement equation: $x(t) = 3t^2 + 5$
Velocity (first derivative of displacement): $v(t) = 6t$
Acceleration (second derivative of displacement): $a(t) = 6$.
Since the acceleration is constant at $6 , \text{m/s}^2$, you can calculate the force as $F = ma$, where $m = 2 \, \text{kg}$. So, $F = 2 \times 6 = 12 \, \text{N}$.
Now, at $t = 5$ seconds, the displacement is $x(5) = 3(5)^2 + 5 = 80 \, \text{m}$.
To calculate the work done, we use $W = F \cdot x$, which gives us $W = 12 \, \text{N} \times 80 \, \text{m} = 960 \, \text{J}$.
Method 2: Using Kinetic Energy
Initial velocity at $t = 0$: $v(0) = 0$
So, the initial kinetic energy is zero.
Final velocity at $t = 5$: $v(5) = 6 \times 5 = 30 \, \text{m/s}$
The final kinetic energy is $$K = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 = \frac{1}{2} \times 2 \times (30)^2 = 900 \, \text{J}.$$
The change in kinetic energy, and therefore the work done, is $ \Delta K = 900 \, \text{J}$.
First method give $W = 960$, whereas the second gives $W = 900$.
The acceleration is constant, then force must be constant over the entire displacement, so $F \cdot x$ must have given the same answer as change in kinetic energy.
Why is such difference?

And what was the displacement at t=0 in method 1?

Why did you put $F\cdot dx$ in your title and not perform integration to solve your problem? Or were you trying to write something like $F\Delta x$?

The displacement in the first approach is incorrect. Note that $x(t)$ is a position function, not a displacement, and that $x(0)=5$. Even though $x(5)=80$, the object has only moved $75$m from where it started, not $80$m. The displacement at time $t$ is equal to $x(t)-x(0)$, not simply $x(t)$.
Many physics problems simplify the bookkeeping by starting with the object at rest at the origin, so it is a bit of a "trick" that $x(0)=5$ here, instead of the more typical $x(0)=0$.
